# Use swfObject to embed flash code?

Tags: javascript, flash, embed, swfobject

I have this embed code for a flash project:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="333" height="380" id="RallyHorseRace">
```

But it is not showing up in Chrome.  **Any suggestions why it is not showing up in Chrome?**

Maybe use swfObject?  But if I use swfObject how do I apply that to this embed code?  Not really familiar with swfObject.

Thanks

ANSWER: I switch it to swfObject and no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had success using swfobject. I would recommend it. Just be aware, if you try to test it from your local hard drive (not through a web server), it may fail silently in some situations.

How to embed it: [look here](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation), specifically in the section "How to embed Flash Player content using SWFObject static publishing".

Answer (score 0):

swfobject's basically just a javascript function that accepts a huge argument list to generate the object/param/embed tag set dynamically. There'd be no real point to using it, except on IE to get around a patent troll's lock on "embedded" content.

Full docs with examples are [here](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation)